# how to implement include guard in lua to prevent lua from loading the same file more than once?

Tags: lua

how do you implement an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in Lua? because when two files `require` the same lua file, sometimes the effect is unexpected. so i want lua to process a file only once.

Comment: `require` already has "include guard".  Please show your code where the "include guard" works incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's usually no need for that.

Luas `require` function first checks the table `package.loaded` for the name you are trying to require and takes that if it exists. If not, and it actually loads the module, it will write it into that table so it can be used the next time.

Put simply: `requrie` is memoized.

Note that this works for usual cases where a module returns a table or a function.

When a module returns `nil`, it will be turned into `true` instead. If, however, the module returns `false`, it will write `false` into `package.loaded`, causing it to be loaded again and again.

---

I just realized that this doesn't anwer the actual question for the offchance that it is actually necessary to use a real include guard.

Needless to say,

## Do not use this unless you know you really need it

Given a module *foo* like this:

```lua
local foo = {}

print 'Loading module; this should only happen once'

function foo.id(...) return ... end

return foo
```

it could easily be modified to something like this:

```lua
local function load()
    local foo = {}

    print 'Loading module; this should only happen once'

    function foo.id(...) return ... end

    return foo
end

if not _G.FOO_HAS_BEEN_LOADED then
    _G.FOO_HAS_BEEN_LOADED = load()
end

return _G.FOO_HAS_BEEN_LOADED
```

I'm using `_G` in hopes that, even if this runs in some weird modified environment, whoever created it has been kind enough to provide the *global environment* in `_G` as one should always do. In normal cases, it doesn't do much, really, unless you have alocal variable named just like your global.

Comment: "*requrie is memoized.*" But it's not "memoized" on a per-*file* basis. It's only done based on the name passed to `require`.

Comment: @NicolBolas It mostly means that you can shoot your own leg if you wish to and that's all. It's more like classical `#ifdef`/`#define` guard rather than `#pragma once` in C terms.